# Counting vectors in $\mathbb{Z}_n^n$ with $0$ as a most common coordinate value

Tags: combinatorics, vectors, combinations

How can we count the number of vectors in $\mathbb{Z}_n^n$ that have $0$  as their **strictly** most common coordinate value appearing exactly $k$ times ? More precisely, if we denote by 
$$\alpha(\mathbf{x},m)=\sum_{k=1}^n \mathbb{1}\{ x_k=m \} $$ the number of times the value $m$ appears as a coordinate in a vector $\mathbf{x}=(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$, then the numbers I am looking for are

$$ \beta(n,k) = \big| \big\{ (x_1, x_2,...,x_n) \in \mathbb{Z}_n^n: \alpha(0) = k, \alpha(\mathbf{x},0)>\alpha(\mathbf{x},m) \quad \mbox{for} \quad m=1,2,...,n-1  \big \}\big|$$

I would also like to count the vectors that have $0$ as the most common coordinate value appearing exactly $k$ times which is the same number of times another coordinate value appears. In this latter case, I would also like to know how many values are tied and the formal definition would be

$$ \hat{\beta}(n,k) = \big| \big\{ (x_1, x_2,...,x_n) \in \mathbb{Z}_n^n: \alpha(\mathbf{x},0) = k, \exists m \in \{1,2,..., n-1\} \quad \mbox{s.t.} \quad \alpha(\mathbf{x},0)=\alpha(\mathbf{x},m)  \big \}\big|$$

For example, if $n=3$, then all $27$ vectors are $(0,0,0), (0,0,1),..., (2,2,2)$, of which there is $1$ that has $0$ as strictly most common coordinate value appearing $3$ times (the vector $(0,0,0)$), there are $6$ that have  $0$ as strictly most common coordinate value appearing $2$ times (those are the vectors $(0,0,1), (0,1,0), (1,0,0), (0,0,2), (0,2,0)$ and $(2,0,0)$) and 6 which have $0$ as the most common value appearing once, but it is not the only most common coordinate value (those are the $6$ permutation and $3$ values are tied). So $\beta(3,3)=1, \beta(3,2) = 6$ and $\hat{\beta}(3,1) = 6$)

**EDIT** When $k>n/2$, calculations are easy as we only need to place the $k$ zeros and fill the remaining places with arbitrary numbers, so $\beta(n,k) = C^k_n \times (n-1)^{(n-k)}$. The problem lies in the case when $k\leq n/2$.

**EDIT 2** Here are some precomputed values :

$\beta(3,k) = [0, 0, 6, 1]$ for $k=0,1,2,3$

$\beta(4,k) = [0, 0, 36, 12, 1]$ for $k=0,1,...,4$

$\beta(5,k) = [0, 0, 240, 160, 20, 1]$ for $k=0,1,...,5$

$\beta(6,k) = [0, 0, 1800, 2400, 375, 30, 1]$ for $k=0,1,...,6$

$\beta(7,k) = [0, 0, 15120, 40950, 7560, 756, 42, 1]$ for $k=0,1,...,7$

and for $n=6$ the $A[i][j]$ entry in the matrix below stores the number of times that $0$ appears a maximal number of times equal to $i$ together with $j$ other values.

[[    0.     0.     0.     0.   720.     0.]

[    5400.   900.     0.     0.     0.     0.]

[    100.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.]

[    0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.]

[    0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.]

[    0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.]]

The same matrix for $n=5$:

[[   0.    0.    0.  120.    0.]

[   360.    0.    0.    0.    0.]

[   0.    0.    0.    0.    0.]

[   0.    0.    0.    0.    0.]

[   0.    0.    0.    0.    0.]]

Comment: You would expect the answer to your first question to be less than $n^{n-1}$ and the sum of the two to be greater than $n^{n-1}$: in your example $7 \lt 3^2 \lt 7+6$

Comment: and the first count should be $\leq \frac{n^n - n!}{n}.$

Comment: Some consecutive desired vals: 7, 49, 421, 4606, 64429 with no OEIS!

Comment: If you are going as $\{0,1,\cdots,n-1\}$ instead as in your previous formulation with $\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$, then change also the title **accordingly** ! . BUT avoid to sensibly change a post after you publish it: it is much annoying and confusing for either for those trying to reply and for any reader !!

Comment: @GCab Relax man, I forgot to update the title; there you have it ! I only wanted to formalise the problem better, as people seem to have shown interest by upvoting and starring. Do you have any ideas of a solution ? I thought of using a dynamic programming approach to get the values, but that would not give a general formula.

Comment: Ok. Yes, I have some idea how to approach this ineteresting, and I am working on that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given an alphabet of $n$ (distinct) characters, which may assumed to be the set $\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$,
the number of words, i.e. lists where order and labeling counts, of length $m$ in which the character $j$ is
repeated $k_j$times is given by the multinomial
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
{{m!} \over {k_{\,1} !k_{\,2} !\; \cdots \;k_{\,n} !}}\quad \left| {\;k_{\,1}  + k_{\,2}  + \; \cdots  + \;k_{\,n} \, = \,m} \right.
} $$

Let us consider  $W(n,m,r)$ as the number of words
 - from alphabet $\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$
 - of length $m$
 - with each character repeated *at most* $r$ times
It can be clearly expressed as
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
W(n,m,r) = \sum\limits_{\left\{ \begin{subarray}{l} 
  0\, \leqslant \,k_{\,j} \; \leqslant \,r \\ 
  k_{\,1}  + k_{\,2}  + \; \cdots  + \;k_{\,n} \, = \,m 
\end{subarray}  \right.\;} {\frac{{m!}}
{{k_{\,1} !k_{\,2} !\; \cdots \;k_{\,n} !}}} 
} \tag {1}$$

Now if one specific character (e.g. $k_n$) is repeated *exactly* $t$ times, while the others
are repeated *at most* $s$ times, then the number of the words so formed will be
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
\begin{gathered}
  W^ *  (n,m,t,s) = \sum\limits_{\left\{ \begin{subarray}{l} 
  k_{\,n}  = t \\ 
  0\, \leqslant \,k_{\,j} \; \leqslant \,s\quad \left| {\;n\, \ne \,j} \right. \\ 
  k_{\,1}  + k_{\,2}  + \; \cdots  + \;k_{\,n} \, = \,m 
\end{subarray}  \right.\;} {\frac{{m!}}
{{k_{\,1} !k_{\,2} !\; \cdots \;k_{\,n} !}}}  =  \hfill \\
   = \sum\limits_{\left\{ \begin{subarray}{l} 
  0\, \leqslant \,k_{\,j} \; \leqslant \,s\quad \left| {\;0\, \leqslant \,j\, \leqslant \,n - 1} \right. \\ 
  k_{\,1}  + k_{\,2}  + \; \cdots  + \;k_{\,n - 1} \, = \,m - t 
\end{subarray}  \right.\;} {\frac{{\left( {m - t} \right)!}}
{{k_{\,1} !k_{\,2} !\; \cdots \;k_{\,n - 1} !}}\frac{{m!}}
{{\left( {m - t} \right)!t!}}}  =  \hfill \\
   = \left( \begin{gathered}
  m \\ 
  t \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)\;W(n - 1,\,m - t,\,s) \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
} \tag {2}$$

Putting $s=t-1$  and summing for $2 \le t \le n$ will give the answer to your problem.

So everything boils down to $W$.
I am not aware of a formulation more "compact" than (1).
However we can compute $W$ also recursively.

In fact, putting $s=r, t=j $ in (2) we get
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
\begin{gathered}
  W(n,m,r) = \sum\limits_{\left\{ \begin{subarray}{l} 
  0\, \leqslant \,k_j \; \leqslant \,r \\ 
  k_{\,1}  + k_{\,2}  + \; \cdots  + \;k_{\,n} \, = \,m 
\end{subarray}  \right.\;} {\frac{{m!}}
{{k_{\,1} !k_{\,2} !\; \cdots \;k_{\,n} !}}}  =  \hfill \\
   = \sum\limits_{0\, \leqslant \,j\; \leqslant \,r} {\;\sum\limits_{\left\{ \begin{subarray}{l} 
  0\, \leqslant \,k_{\,l} \; \leqslant \,r\quad \left| {\;0\, \leqslant \,l\, \leqslant \,n - 1} \right. \\ 
  k_{\,1}  + k_{\,2}  + \; \cdots  + \;k_{\,n - 1} \, = \,m - j 
\end{subarray}  \right.\;} {\frac{{\left( {m - j} \right)!}}
{{k_{\,1} !k_{\,2} !\; \cdots \;k_{\,n} !}}\frac{{m!}}
{{\left( {m - j} \right)!j!}}} }  =  \hfill \\
   = \sum\limits_{0\, \leqslant \,j\; \leqslant \,r} {\left( \begin{gathered}
  m \\ 
  j \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)\;W(n - 1,\,m - j,\,r)}  \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
} \tag {3.a}$$
with starting conditions to be properly established.
In fact, it is sufficient to put
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
\left\{ \begin{gathered}
  W(n,\,m,\,r) = 0\quad \left| {\;n < 0\; \vee \;m < 0\; \vee \;r < 0} \right. \hfill \\
  W(n,\,0,\,r) = 1\;\left( {\text{empty}\;\text{word}} \right) \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.
} \tag {3.b}$$
since other "obvious" values like
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
\left\{ \begin{gathered}
  W(n,\,m,\,r) = 0\quad \left| {\;rn < m} \right. \hfill \\
  W(n,\,m,\,1) = n^{\,\underline {\,m\,} }  \hfill \\
  W(1,\,m,\,r) = \left[ {m \leqslant r} \right] = \left( \begin{gathered}
  m - r \\ 
  m - r \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right) \hfill \\
  W(n,\,1,\,r) = n\left[ {1 \leqslant r} \right] \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.
} \tag {3.c}$$
follow from that. 
A LU decomposition of  $W$ rendered as matrix gives
$$
W(n,m,r) = \sum\limits_{0\, \leqslant \,k\; \leqslant \,n\;} {\left( \begin{gathered}
  n \\ 
  k \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)k!T(k,m,r)}  = \sum\limits_{0\, \leqslant \,k\; \leqslant \,n\;} {T(k,m,r)\,n^{\,\underline {\,k\,} } } 
$$
where:
$T(n,m,2)$ is [OEIS A144331](http://oeis.org/A144331),
$T(n,m,3)$ is [OEIS A144385](http://oeis.org/A144385),
$T(n,m,4)$ is [OEIS A144643](http://oeis.org/A144643) ....

The above shows a parallelism with the tranformation $n^m\; \to \; n^{\,\underline {\,k\,} }$ through Stirling N. 2nd kind.
If so, $T(n,m,r)$ shall read similar to the transposed of the Stirling N., i.e. as $\left\{ \begin{gathered} m \\  n \\  \end{gathered}  \right\}$,
and in fact, very interestingly, in OEIS it is defined as
*number of partitions of an m-set into n nonempty subsets, each of size at most r*.

Comment: Interesting, indeed and a nice approach. I'm curious to see this story going on ... (+1)

Comment: @MarkusScheuer: thanks, initial conditions are now established. Do you (or every other reader) know some existing works about "Number of words with given max repetition" ?